# how to pass a value to the authorization value dynamically

Tags: flask, swagger-ui

I want to pass the Value variable dynamically how can I do that.

here...

[image]

my code:

```
 authorizations = {
    'apikey': {
       'description': 'test',
       'type': 'apiKey',
       'in': 'header',
       'name': 'API-KEY'
    }
  }


# Creating Swagger Documentation.
area_api = Api(areaB, doc='/doc', version='1.0', title='AREA',
                        description='Area Location Information', authorizations=authorizations)

area = area_api.namespace('area', desciption="Area Location Information")

def token_required(req_data):
   @wraps(req_data)
   def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
      token = None
      if 'API-KEY' in request.headers:
          token = request.headers['API-KEY']
      if not token:
          return {'message': 'Token is missing'}
      try:
        pub_key = open(PUB_SECRET_KEY).read()
        data = jwt.decode(token, pub_key, algorithm='HS256')
      except jwt.InvalidTokenError:
         return jsonify({'message': 'Token is invalid'})
      except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
        return jsonify({'token expired': 'Please log in again'})
      return req_data(*args, **kwargs)

    return decorated


  @area.route("/getallareas")
  @area.response('200', 'Success', headers={'Authorization': 'Token'})
  @area.doc(security='apikey')
  class GetAllRoomAreaV(Resource):
      @staticmethod
      @token_required
      def get():
        """ Returns all the Areas """
        return jsonify(get_all_AreaC())
```

I don't no where to pass the jwt key.I have tried to pass the JWT key at the headers but it didn't worked

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "pass a value dynamically"?

Comment: @Helen I mean...I have the Token in one variable..I want to pass the token automatically